# UITabbarItem : - Downloaded image does not show up at Tabbar Item.

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I am fetching the image url in the json response from server and downloading image using SdWebimage framework which is downloading fine. But when I set this downloading image object to tabbar item , it does not show the image instead it shows the grey square box there.

Also, tried resizing the image to 30*30 px,checked image at url by putting the image url to browser.

This code I'm using to set my image to tabbaritem.....

```
myImgView.sd_setImageWithURL(url!, placeholderImage: pImage, options:.HighPriority, completed: { (image, error, cahce, url) in
            tabbarItem.image = image
        })
```

If anyone could tell me to properly set downloaded image to tabbaritem's icon ?

[image]

Comment: How did you access the UIImageView instance myImgView? Where are you calling this function from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is downloading. The problem is the `UITabBarItem`'s only use the alpha component of the image. Since your image is completely opaque it is showing up as a gray square. You can change this behavior by setting the `UIRenderingMode` of the image to be `.AlwaysOriginal`. For example:

```
image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

You can then set image to the tab bar item but it will render like a normal image and may not match your other items if they are using template images.